# Python Define Unit Test Classes Together with Code

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am rapid prototyping so for now I would like to write unit tests together with the code I am testing - rather than putting the tests in a separate file.  However, I would only like to build the test an invoke them if we run the code in the containing file as main.  As follows:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init(self)__:
        # do init stuff here

    def myclassFunction():
        # do something


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest

    class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_one(self):
            # test myclassFunction()

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestMyClass)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

This of course doesn't run as unittest is unable to find or make use of the test class, TestMyClass.  Is there a way to get this arrangement to work or do I have to pull everything out of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` scope except the invocation to unittest?

Thanks!

Comment: *Pyret* is a Python dialect that is designed to interleave methods with tests for them...

Comment: "I am rapid prototyping". How much time have you saved by doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you move your `TestMyClass` above of `if __name__ == '__main__'`
you will get exactly what you want:
Tests will run only when file executed as main

Something like this

```
import unittest
class MyClass:
  def __init(self)__:
    # do init stuff here

  def myclassFunction():
    # do something


class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_one(self):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You are right but that was the meaning of the last part of my question. Is there a way to make it work without pulling the test class out of the if __ name__ block?

Comment: Why actually you might want to do this , @Colin?

Comment: Unit test in the same file?  Truly saves time when debugging, especially when the class definition is unstable.  Also, I would prefer to keep the unit test classes apart when inside the same file.  The alternative, of course, is as shown in this answer, which isn't so bad but not as nice.